# How to remove the red squiggly line from IntelliSense for the newly created table or procedure without restarting the SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, intellisense

A newly created table or procedure will always have the red squiggly underline until the SQL Server Management Studio is restarted. Is there a way to get rid of it without re-start the SSMS? Or it's a feature that SSMS needs to update? Thanks!

Comment: Well, the answer there certainly address my question. It's just when I searched before I asked this question, it doesn't show up. The question about updating the IntelliSense cache is more or less part of the answer to this question, not necessary a duplicate. The person who asked the question obviously knows the red squiggly underline is due to the IntelliSense cache, just doesn't know how to update it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try pressing ctrl + Shift + r to refresh intellisense and remove the red squiggly underline.